# React hooks - onClick and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React Hooks is not updating to use the prop passed down and then stored. Usually I would resolve useState issues by calling functionality inside useEffect but in this case I need to update after a click event:

```
const [currentLayer, setCurrentLayer] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.currentLayer) // props.currentLayer is defined
    setCurrentLayer(props.currentLayer);
}, [props.currentLayer]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentLayer); // currentLayer state is defined
}, [currentLayer]);

/*
 * Called when the timeline product is clicked
 */
const clickHandler = e => {
    console.log(currentLayer); // currentLayer state is undefined
    currentLayer.getSource().updateParams({ TIME: e.time });
};

return <Timeline options={props.timelineOptions} items={items} clickHandler={e => clickHandler(e)} />;
```

When clickHandler is called currentLayer state is undefined despite having been set earlier.

What is the best way to combine useEffect and the clickHandler, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Is a working example really required to suggest a solution for how to combine useEffect and a click handler?

Comment: Why are you applying `props.currentLayer` to state in the first place? It looks like you don't need to and making copies of data should be avoided where possible

Comment: I thought so initially as well, in creating a working example for this question I don't have the same issue, something else must be causing the problem.

Comment: Your logic is fine, you need a producible example as @T.J.Crowder suggested because you getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: I have since tried and can't replicate the issue: https://codepen.io/alexplummer/pen/mddPKRq

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'

const Component = (props) => {

  // ... your other logic

  const [currentLayer, setCurrentLayer] = useState(props.currentLayer)

  const clickHandler = e => {
    currentLayer.getSource().updateParams({ TIME: e.time });
  }

  return <Timeline options={props.timelineOptions} items={items} clickHandler={clickHandler} />

}
```

I don't see a reason why you need the useEffect hook. In fact, you should not set the currentLayer props in this component but rather use it as it is. This is so that when there is a change in the props.currentLayer, this component will also re-render.

Comment: Yeah I thought so initially, and in creating a working example I can't actually replicate the issue, something else must be causing this like a cached instance of the clickhandler function..

Comment: Your `currentLayer` won't be updated on `props.currentLayer` change, thats why `useEffect` needed

Comment: How would I combine this with a clickHandler?

Answer (score 0):

```
        const clickHandler = e => {
            props.currentLayer.getSource().updateParams({ TIME: e.time });
        };
```